# Spark unable to read parquet file from partitioned S3 bucket

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have my S3 bucket partitioned like this:

```
bucket
|--2018
|--2019
    |--01
    |--02
       |--01
          |--files.parquet
...
```

It works fine when I read using this command (Spark 2.1.1):

```
val dfo = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://bucket/2019/04/03/*")
```

but it hits an error when I try to add a partition variable to the path:

```
val dfo = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://bucket/2019/04/day=03/*")
or
val dfo = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://bucket/y=2019/m=04/day=03")
```

Error:

```
Name: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException
Message: Path does not exist: s3://bucket/2019/04/day=03/*;
StackTrace:   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:377)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:370)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:441)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:425)
```

Comment: The S3 file structure you have is not a partitioning structure. Correct partitioned structure should be like 's3://bucket/year=2019/month=04/day=03/'.

Comment: @Munesh thanks for the response. not sure if I understand, you mean I need to change the structure on s3? in the code adding a variable to all of them didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes. You need to update your s3 structure to treat the data as partitioned.

Comment: @Munesh could you make an example or link to a reference?